# How do I get a modal dialog in a Firefox extension to be centered on the screen?

Tags: firefox-addon, modal-dialog

If I have a dialog and I want to center it on the screen, I can just do something like:

```
var w = window.openDialog('chrome://syndicus/content/saveDialog.xul', '', 'chrome,dialog');
w.centerWindowOnScreen();
```

but if it's a *modal* dialog, then the `openDialog` function doesn't return until after the user has pressed something, so `centerWindowOnScreen` won't get called until it's too late. How can I center a modal dialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding "centerscreen" to the feature.

```
window.openDialog('chrome://syndicus/content/saveDialog.xul', '', 'chrome,dialog,centerscreen');
```

Comment: D'oh! And it's listed right here too. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open

Comment: It does not work in Thunderbird on MacOS. It is centered in horizontal but in vertical it is displayed in random positions.

Answer (score 2):

Put the call to `centerWindowOnScreen` in the JavaScript of the dialog itself:

```
<dialog xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
        buttons="accept,cancel"
        ondialogaccept="onAccept();"
        ondialogcancel="onCancel();">
  <script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      window.centerWindowOnScreen();
    }, false);
    // more JavaScript ...
  ]]></script>
</dialog>
```

Comment: This was not immediately obvious to me, so I thought I'd throw it out as a SO question. If anyone knows a better way than this, please feel free to post it.